# Apache and VirtualHosts in RedHat, Can't figure it out

Tags: centos, apache-2.4, redhat, virtualhost, http

already did my research and Im burned after reading and watching videos for hours; I can't make virtual hosts works at all, it doest matter which configuration I set but Apache will ignore it and always try to load the content within /var/www/html

The goal is to write the address on a browser and access different sites like this app.example.ca, blog.example.ca, [www.example.ca](http://www.example.ca) (Im running a recursive DNS server)

My current configuration (Although I've tried many others) is the next one:

http.conf (Default config, added a line):

```
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

app.conf (Only virtual host config file):

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName app.friscia.ca
        ServerAlias app.friscia.ca
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/app
        ErrorLog /var/www/html/app/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

DNS Zone Content:

```
$TTL 10800      ; 3 hours
friscia.ca              IN SOA  friscia.ca. hostmaster.friscia.ca. (
                                7          ; serial
                                86400      ; refresh (1 day)
                                3600       ; retry (1 hour)
                                604800     ; expire (1 week)
                                10800      ; minimum (3 hours)
                                )
                        NS      ns1.friscia.ca.
                        NS      ns2.friscia.ca.
                        A       10.211.55.10
$ORIGIN friscia.ca.
$TTL 300        ; 5 minutes
EZEQUIELLFR2FBC         A       10.211.55.100
                        TXT     "31ed3c4417f785d3f24002d6f3c02f2edc"
$TTL 10800      ; 3 hours
ns1                     A       10.211.55.10
ns2                     A       10.211.55.11
www                     A       10.211.55.10
app                     A       10.211.55.10
```

Comment: I've disabled SELinux just to keep it simple until everything works, user and group owners of related files are set to apache.

Comment: Your IP is within the private range `10.0.0.0/8`, thus it can only be reached from within this network (usually an intranet), and not from the internet. Are you trying to connect from within this network? Also, your VHost config lacks the TLS/SSL key and certificate(s) which will lead to further errors

Comment: Yes, it’s just to access within my intranet / lab. If I modify my hosts file it works, but just from the hosting gym of course.

Comment: Does an unencrypted connection (`<VirtualHost *:80>`) work?

Comment: Same results. Trying to load only from /var/www/html/index.html ignoring virtual host config.

Comment: Please provide the exact error message you receive when you try this configuration.

Comment: There's no error message at all; I just see the "Red Hat Enterprise Linux Test Page" whatever I try. If I put content in the folder /var/www/html it will load, but any VirtualHost configuration won't.

Comment: Did you restart or reload Apache after modifying the configuration files?

Comment: I did; I know DNS records are working since I write the addresses www.friscia.ca, app.friscia.ca or blog.friscia.ca and I get somewhere, even from others devices in the network, but well, always the same place.

Comment: Then please provide the rest of your Apache configuration. The issue is not in the part you showed.

Comment: Alright, I've deleted mod_ssl and now everything runs on 80. What's wrong with 443 and how could I make it work? Ports are allowed on firewall-cmd.

Comment: You'll have to switch on `SSLEngine` and provide it with a key and a certificate [see manual here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Will read about it.